# Adding category dropdown list to theme options page

Tags: categories, list

I am tyring to add a category drop down list to my theme options page. I am try it this way:

```
<p>
            Select a style from the list
            <?php
            $amp_categories_obj = get_categories('hide_empty=0');
   $amp_categories = array();
   foreach ($amp_categories_obj as $amp_cat) {
   $amp_categories[$amp_cat->cat_ID] = $amp_cat->category_nicename;
   }
   $categories_tmp = array_unshift($amp_categories, "Select a category:"); 

   echo "<select name='amp_options[amp_cat]'>";
   foreach ($amp_categories_obj as $amp_cat) {
    $selected = ($options['amp_cat']==$amp_cat) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
    echo "<option value='$amp_cat' $selected>$amp_cat</option>";
   }
   echo "</select>";

   ?>
            </p>
```

I am not much of a PHP coder by the way. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't worry, I made it work; like this:

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories(); ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories

Comment: I amde it work:
<p>
            Select a category for your slider from the list
   <?php
   $categories=  get_categories(); 

            echo "<select name='amp_options[amp_cat]'>";
            foreach ($categories as $cat) {
                $selected = ($cat->cat_name==$options['amp_cat']) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
                echo "<option value='$cat->cat_name' $selected>$cat->name</option>";
            }
            echo "</select>";

   ?>
            </p>

Comment: @Towfiq: Please add you solution as an answer to your question and mark it as the solution.